# Worldpay Token Confusion

Tags: worldpay

Trying to implement Worldpay integration. The docs at https://online.worldpay.com/docs/take-card-details-templates mention a token. I have tested the page and I dont get any token. Wandering how i can get this token.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="payment2.aspx.cs" Inherits="payment2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src= "https://cdn.worldpay.com/v1/worldpay.js">
      </script>        

      <script type='text/javascript'>
          window.onload = function () {
              Worldpay.setClientKey('T_C_a453a70e-c5e6-4618-9c7b-96f787f0fa04');
              Worldpay.reusable = false;
              Worldpay.useTemplate('payment-form', 'my_payment_section', 'inline');
          }
      </script>
</head>
<body>
     <form action="/complete" id="payment-form" method="post">     

      <!— all other fields you want to collect, e.g. name
        and shipping address -->  

      <div id='my_payment_section'></div>

      <div>
          <input type="submit" value="Place Order" />
      </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When the window.onload executes, it puts the WorldPay card capture form on your page.  By the looks of it, you haven't disabled their Save Payment button, so are you trying to use your own submit button??  If you are trying to use your submit button, then you should add the onclick attribute to submit the worldpay template.

```
<input type="submit" value="Place Order" />
<form action="/complete" id="payment-form" method="post">
    <div id="my_payment_section"></div>
    <div>
        <input id="submitCard" onclick="Worldpay.submitTemplateForm()" value="Confirm Payment" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Once the form submits, worldpay.js takes over, and it will handle the sensitive card information, validate it and if all is ok, it will replace the cardDetails div with a single hidden input field which is the token.

If that all happens correctly, with no errors, after the token input has been placed in the DOM, the form will submit to your action "/complete", and the token will be part of the submitted values of the form.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is missing the callback to generate the token in useTemplate()
See: https://developer.worldpay.com/jsonapi/docs/template-form

The callback generates the hidden input with the token value for you which posts to worldpay.

your script should be:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onload = function() {
      Worldpay.useTemplateForm({
        'clientKey':'T_C_a453a70e-c5e6-4618-9c7b-96f787f0fa04',
        'form':'paymentForm',
        'paymentSection':'paymentSection',
        'display':'inline',
        'reusable':false,
        'callback': function(obj) {
          if (obj && obj.token) {
            var _el = document.createElement('input');
            _el.value = obj.token;
            _el.type = 'hidden';
            _el.name = 'token';
            document.getElementById('paymentForm').appendChild(_el);
            document.getElementById('paymentForm').submit();
          }
        }
      });
    }
    </script>
```

You also need the onclick="Worldpay.submitTemplateForm()" attribute on your submit too.